# How to use instant with ngx-translate

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

I'm using ngx-translate with Angular 4 and I have a problem when I change the language. It works for statics values in HTML but not strings in services.

The documentation says :

> instant(key: string|Array, interpolateParams?: Object): string|Object: Gets the instant translated value of a key (or an array of keys). /!\ This method is synchronous and the default file loader is asynchronous. You are responsible for knowing when your translations have been loaded and it is safe to use this method. If you are not sure then you should use the get method instead.

I have no idea how to use it. When I try "translate.instant" in my service, I get the key but not the value.

Can I get more explanations about how to use instant ?

Comment: Hmmm came across your post now - it might be that upon changing languages a digest is done when the alternate language file hasn't properly been loaded in memory. Did you manage to find a solution to your issue? And was it 100% necessary to use the synchronous 'instant' method instead of the async 'get'?

Comment: I managed to work with translate.instant :  this.translateService.instant('my-translate'); And when I click to change language, I'm using this event :  this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => { translate.use(event.lang).subscribe(() => this.refreshTranslation());} hope it helps you

Comment: Hi, 
when I try to use .instant() function, I have this error `this.translate is undefined`. I've instantiate it like this : `constructor (
        translate: TranslateService
    ) {
        translate.setDefaultLang('en');
        translate.use('en');
    }`
How did you manage to make it work ? :-)

Comment: Did you provide the translateService in your module.ts ?